# Unable to get CallableThread in RejectionHandler

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpoolexecutor

I have thread pool, which will take `Callable` worker thread with a `RejectionHandler`. I need to get this Callable task in `RejectionHandler` but unable to get it.

In this below example, I need uniqueId of Callable task for which RejectionHandler executed. In `RejecitonHandler`, the `Runnable` is casted `FutureTask` where I expect that it should be casted to `Callable` worker thread.

Please help me in getting `Callable` Worker thread instance in `RejectionHandler`.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class RejectionDemo {
    RejectionDemo(){
        Random random = new Random();
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(2), new RejectionHandlerImpl());
        CallableWorkerThread workers[] = 
                new CallableWorkerThread[10];
        for (int i=0; i< workers.length; i++){
            workers[i] = new CallableWorkerThread(random.nextInt(100));
            FutureTask<Integer> task = new FutureTask<Integer>(workers[i]);
            executor.submit(task);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        RejectionDemo demo = new RejectionDemo();
    }
    public class CallableWorkerThread implements
        Callable<Integer> {
        private int uniqueId;

        CallableWorkerThread(int uniqueId) {
            this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
        }

        public Integer call() {
            System.out.println("Unique id="+uniqueId);
            return uniqueId;
        }
        public String toString(){
            return ""+uniqueId;
        }
    }
    class RejectionHandlerImpl implements RejectedExecutionHandler{
        public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
            try{
                System.out.println(r);
            }catch(Throwable t){
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@70036428
Unique id=68
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@6ea4b78b
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@e3f6d
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@1ce84763
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@55a6c368
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@4e77b794
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@15b57dcb
Unique id=55
Unique id=83
```

I am expecting CallableWorkerThread instead of FutureTask. Help me in getting WorkerThread instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code

```
workers[i] = new CallableWorkerThread(random.nextInt(100));
FutureTask<Integer> task = new FutureTask<Integer>(workers[i]);
executor.submit(task);
```

you create a `FutureTask` which wraps the `CallableWorkerThread` instance but then you are using `submit` which accepts an arbitrary `Runnable` and returns a `FutureTask` which wraps the `Runnable`.

In other words, you are wrapping your `FutureTask` in another `FutureTask`. There are two ways to solve this

1. Use

   ```
   workers[i] = new CallableWorkerThread(random.nextInt(100));
   executor.submit(workers[i]);
   ```

   to let the `ExecutorService` wrap your `Callable` inside a `FutureTask`.
2. Use

   ```
   workers[i] = new CallableWorkerThread(random.nextInt(100));
   executor.execute(new FutureTask<Integer>(workers[i]));
   ```

   to wrap the `Callable` manually and enqueue it as `Runnable` without further wrapping (note the use of `execute` rather than `submit`)

Since you want to enable retrieval of the original `Callable`, the second option is for you, as it gives you full control over the `FutureTask` instance:

```
static class MyFutureTask<T> extends FutureTask<T> {
    final Callable<T> theCallable;

    public MyFutureTask(Callable<T> callable) {
        super(callable);
        theCallable=callable;
    }
}
```

submitting code:

```
    for (int i=0; i< workers.length; i++){
        workers[i] = new CallableWorkerThread(random.nextInt(100));
        executor.execute(new MyFutureTask<Integer>(workers[i]));
    }
```

RejectedExecutionHandler:

```
class RejectionHandlerImpl implements RejectedExecutionHandler{
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor) {
        if(r instanceof MyFutureTask) {
            MyFutureTask<?> myFutureTask = (MyFutureTask)r;
            Callable<?> c=myFutureTask.theCallable;
            System.out.println(c);
        }
        else System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: try{
    Class aClass = r.getClass();
    System.out.println("CName:"+aClass.getName());
    Field field = aClass.getDeclaredField("callable");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    System.out.println("Runnable:"+field.getType());
   }catch(Throwable t){
    t.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println();
   }

Comment: The above code block worked. What is the difference between submit() and execute()? Are both these calls non-blocking calls?

Comment: @sunrise76: yes, both are non-blocking. `submit` returns a `Future` representing the state of the execution. This is implemented by creating a `FutureTask` which implements `Future` *and* `Runnable`. This `FutureTask` will be put into the queue of `Runnable`s and returned as `Future`. In contrast, `execute` returns nothing but simply puts the `Runnable` directly into the queue. By creating a `FutureTask` manually and putting into the queue via `execute` you retrace what `submit` normally does, except that you have full control over the `FutureTask`, i.e. you may use a subclass of `FutureTask`.