# get callable from ThreadPoolTaskExecutor or cast Runnable to Callable

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, threadpoolexecutor

I'm using [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) for executing my tasks which are implemantations of [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) interface. I just want to check in time if task is still in pool (monitoring). How to do that? I know that I can get queue from [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html?is-external=true) but how can I cast Runnable to Callable?

Basically I have this callable

```
public interface IFormatter extends Callable<Integer>{
    Long getOrderId();
}
```

I'm executing it like this

```
ThreadPoolExecutor.submit(new Formatter(order));
```

And finally I'd like to loop through queue of ExecutorService in some async method and check if thread with orderId is still there.

Comment: You can’t, as these `Runnable`s are actually `FutureTask` instances wrapping the original `Callable`. To make the original `Callable` accessible, you have to replace the `ExecutorService`-generated `FutureTask`s by manually created ones. Compare with [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30789565/2711488).

Comment: I've updated my question. Is it somehow possible to call getOrderId with your solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30789565/2711488), you may get control over the `FutureTask` wrapping the `Callable` by creating it manually and enqueuing via `execute`. Otherwise, `submit` will wrap your `Callable` into an `ExecutorService`-specific object and put it into the queue, making it impossible to query properties of the `Callable` via standard APIs.

Using the custom `FutureTask`

```
class MyFutureTask extends FutureTask<Integer> {
    final IFormatter theCallable;

    public MyFutureTask(IFormatter callable) {
        super(callable);
        theCallable=callable;
    }
    Long getOrderId() {
        return theCallable.getOrderId();
    }
}
```

enqueuing it via `threadPoolExecutor.execute(new MyFutureTask(new Formatter(order)));`,

you can query order IDs on the queue:

```
public static boolean isEnqueued(ThreadPoolExecutor e, Long id) {
    for(Object o: e.getQueue().toArray()) {
        if(o instanceof MyFutureTask && Objects.equals(((MyFutureTask)o).getOrderId(), id))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This works for any `ExecutorService` (assuming it has a queue). If you are using a `ThreadPoolExecutor` only, you may customize its creation of `FutureTask` instance (starting with Java 6), instead of relying on the submitter doing it:

```
public class MyThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    public MyThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime,
                                TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue);
    }
    public MyThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime,
        TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit,
            workQueue, threadFactory);
    }
    public MyThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime,
        TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue,
        RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit,
            workQueue, handler);
    }
    public MyThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime,
        TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, ThreadFactory threadFactory,
        RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit,
            workQueue, threadFactory, handler);
    }

    @Override
    protected <T> RunnableFuture<T> newTaskFor(Callable<T> callable) {
        if(callable instanceof IFormatter)
            return (FutureTask<T>)new MyFutureTask((IFormatter)callable);
        return super.newTaskFor(callable);
    }
}
```

Then, using an instance of `MyThreadPoolExecutor` instead of `ThreadPoolExecutor` every submission of an `IFormatter` instance will automatically wrapped using `MyFutureTask` instead of the standard `FutureTask`. The drawback is that this works only with this specific `ExecutorService` and the generic method generates an unchecked warning for the special treatment.

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you want to monitor the ExecutorService, look into overriding `decorateTask()`. You can then decorate the future to monitor its state.

Comment: The method `decorateTask` is defined in `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, not `ThreadPoolExecutor`. The general solution for all subclasses of `AbstractExecutorService` is to override `newTaskFor`.