# How to get the task's field in the RejectedExecutionHandler?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I want to know the `Task` which is rejected by the executor.For example,i want to get the name of the rejected task.But in the `RejectedExecutionHandler`,i can't do this!

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(),
            (Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor1) -> {
                //TODO 
                //want to get the task name 
                System.out.println("in reject:");
    });
    Task t1 = new Task("t1");
    Task t2 = new Task("t2");
    Future<Integer> t1Fe = executor.submit(t1);
    Future<Integer> t2Fe =  executor.submit(t2);

    System.out.println(t1Fe.get());
    System.out.println(t2Fe.get());
}

static class Task implements Callable{
    private String name;

    public Task(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(1);
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Task gets wrapped into a FutureTask which does not provide a getter to the Task. You can use reflection to access the `callable` field of the `FutureTask` but that's not a very robust approach.

Comment: Override RejectedExecutionHandler and create your own. It's the best way.

Comment: @canillas that's what has been done in the code in the question. The question is how to access the underlying Task from the Runnable.

Comment: @assylias I don't see your custom handler in the code... Something like `public class MyRejectedExecutionHandler implements RejectedExecutionHandler {`

Comment: It's there: `(Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor1) -> { System.out.println("in reject:");   });`

Comment: @assylias I answered my question myself,thank you.

Comment: Very similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30789402/2711488)…

Answer (score 1):

I override the `submit` method and override the `FutureTask` class!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(),
            (Runnable r, ThreadPoolExecutor executor1) -> {
                //TODO
                //want to get the task name
                MyFutureTask task = (MyFutureTask)r;
                System.out.println("in reject:"+task.name);
    });
    Task t1 = new Task("t1");
    Task t2 = new Task("t2");
    Future<Integer> t1Fe = submit(executor,t1);
    Future<Integer> t2Fe =  submit(executor,t2);

    System.out.println(t1Fe.get());
    System.out.println(t2Fe.get());
}

public static Future submit(ThreadPoolExecutor executor,Callable task) {
    if (task == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    MyFutureTask ftask = new MyFutureTask(task);
    ftask.setName(((Task)task).name);
    executor.execute(ftask);
    return ftask;
}

static class MyFutureTask extends FutureTask{
    private String name;
    public MyFutureTask(Callable callable) {
        super(callable);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
static class Task implements Callable{
    private String name;

    public Task(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(1);
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nicely done - alternatively you could extend ThreadPoolExecutor and override the 3 `submit` methods.

Comment: @assylias: better, override [`newTaskFor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#newTaskFor-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) which is exactly made for this purpose; then, you don’t need to override all `submit` methods nor fear that future versions might offer additional submission methods you haven’t overridden…